# Evernote: script that can incrementally download full db where note = file?

Tags: backup, cron, git, evernote

Is there any script to incrementally download my Evernote database in plaintext? I need to have not one big file but many files (with attachments) - I want to use `cron` for everyday backup to `git` and git works better with many little files rather that with one big file - and I need to see the diff and have the ability to see the note's content in a web-browser-view of git-repository.

`gnsync` from Geeknote - can't download all my notes, isn't a good solution for less than ~900 notes

`Nixnote` - I can backup only big sqlite-db file.

I have more than 3500 notes, 4.5G - size of manually exported xml from Nixnote (with attachments), sqlite-db with only text data ~170 mb